# JSF selectOneMenu

Tags: jsf, selectonemenu, postconstruct

I am new in JSF and facing problem in getting the drop down list. I don't want to use the `@PostConstructor`. I tried couple of sources on google but i don't know where i am making the mistake. please hep me out.

**Managed Bean**

```
package com.employee.registration;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class EmployeeBean implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5400118477202860998L;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String emailID;
    private int employeeNumber;
    private String employeeDepartment;
    private String dplist;
    private List<DepartmentList> departmentList;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getEmailID() {
        return emailID;
    }

    public void setEmailID(String emailID) {
        this.emailID = emailID;
    }

    public int getEmployeeNumber() {
        return employeeNumber;
    }

    public void setEmployeeNumber(int employeeNumber) {
        this.employeeNumber = employeeNumber;
    }

    public String getEmployeeDepartment() {
        return employeeDepartment;
    }

    public void setEmployeeDepartment(String employeeDepartment) {
        this.employeeDepartment = employeeDepartment;
    }

    public List<DepartmentList> getDepartmentList() {
        return departmentList;
    }

    public void setDepartmentList(List<DepartmentList> departmentList) {
        this.departmentList = departmentList;
    }

    public List<DepartmentList> getDepartments() {
        departmentList = new ArrayList<DepartmentList>();
        departmentList.add(new DepartmentList("1", "Finance"));
        departmentList.add(new DepartmentList("2", "Bnking"));
        return departmentList;
    }

    public String getDplist() {
        return dplist;
    }

    public void setDplist(String dplist) {
        this.dplist = dplist;
    }

}
```

---

**Java Class**

```
package com.employee.registration;

public class DepartmentList {

private String departmentId;
private String departmentName;

public DepartmentList(String departmentId, String departmentName) {
    this.departmentId = departmentId;
    this.departmentName = departmentName;
}

public String getDepartmentId() {
    return departmentId;
}

public void setDepartmentId(String departmentId) {
    this.departmentId = departmentId;
}

public String getDepartmentName() {
    return departmentName;
}

public void setDepartmentName(String departmentName) {
    this.departmentName = departmentName;
}
```

}

---

**XHTML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<h:head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
    <title>Employee Registration</title>
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="stylesheet.css" />
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Enter the Employees Information </legend>

            <h:outputLabel id="firstName" value="First Name :" for="fName"></h:outputLabel>
            <h:inputText id="fName" value="#{employeeBean.firstName}"
                required="true"></h:inputText>
            <br></br>

            <h:outputLabel id="lastName" value="Last Name :" for="lName"></h:outputLabel>
            <h:inputText id="lName" value="#{employeeBean.lastName}"
                required="true"></h:inputText>
            <br></br>

            <h:outputLabel id="emailId" value="Email ID :"></h:outputLabel>
            <h:inputText id="email" value="#{employeeBean.emailID}"
                required="true"></h:inputText>
            <br></br>

            <h:outputLabel id="employeeNumberId" value="Employee Number :"></h:outputLabel>
            <h:inputText id="empNumber" value="#{employeeBean.employeeNumber}"></h:inputText>
            <br></br>

            <h:outputLabel id="employeeDepartmentID" value="Employee Department"></h:outputLabel>
            <h:inputText id="eDepartment"
                value="#{employeeBean.employeeDepartment}"></h:inputText>
            <br></br>

            <h:selectOneMenu value="#{employeeBean.dplist}"></h:selectOneMenu>
            <f:selectItems value="#{employeeBean.departmentList}" var="e"
                itemLabel="#{e.departmentId}" itemValue="#{e.departmentName}"></f:selectItems>
            <h:commandButton id="submit" value="Submit"
                action="outputInformation"></h:commandButton>

        </fieldset>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: Besides that duplicate, you'd better also read http://stackoverflow.com/q/7031885 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/2090033 to realize how wrong and inefficient your current code is.

Comment: And, for future questions, please carefully read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve how to come up with a proper code snippet. E.g. all those other fields in your bean and the `<br>` and `<h:outputLabel>` etc tags surely don't contribute to the actual problem, hereby only causing noise.

Answer (score 0):

selectItems tag should be inside selectOneMenu :)

```
        <h:selectOneMenu value="#{employeeBean.dplist}}">
            <f:selectItems value="#{employeeBean.departmentList}" var="e"
            itemLabel="#{e.departmentId}" itemValue="#{e.departmentName}" />
        </h:selectOneMenu>
```

see tutorial [here](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-dropdown-box-example/)